# Ruby On Rails API Update Record Only If User Logged In Matches Email

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey everyone so i am currently writing an API on Ruby on Rails and kind of hit a brick wall on updating an establishment in the database.

What i am trying to accomplish:

If the user who is currently logged in has the same matching email as the email address associated with an establishment, allow that user to update the establishments information.

Unfortunately I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to verify the current user who is logged in matches the establishments email on file. Any Help id appreciate. Thank you

Here is my Code:

```
def update
    establishment = Establishment.update(establishment_params)
    current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]

    if !session[:user_id]
      render json: {status: 'Information Updated'}, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {status: 'Not Verified'}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def establishment_params
    params.permit(
      :name,
      :address,
      :city,
      :state,
      :zipcode,
      :phone    
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps give something like this a try:

```
  def update
    if authorized?
      establishment.assign_attributes(establishment_params)
      if establishment.valid?
        establishment.save!
        render json: {status: 'Information Updated'}, status: :ok
      else
        render json: {status: 'Not Updated', errors: establishment.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      render json: {status: 'Not Verified'}, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

private

  def authorized?
    # Guessing at how to access email addresses. You'll need to fix to fit
    # your actual record structures.
    return false unless current_user && current_user.email_address
    return false unless establishment && establishment.email_address
    current_user.email_address == establishment.email_address
  end

  def establishment
    # memoization for @establishment
    @establishment ||= find_establishment 
  end

  def find_establishment
    # Will throw an error if Establishment not found. Guessing on 
    # params[:id]. You'll need to correct to wherever/however you 
    # pass in the Establishment id.
    Establishment.find(params[:id])
  end
```

In creating your API, you probably want to use `:unprocessable_entity` and `:unauthorized` in ways that are reasonably conventional. Returning status of `:unprocessable_entity` when a user is unauthorized seems unconventional to me. I would suggest that's what the status `:unauthorized` is for.

Also, personally, I prefer the memoization approach to the `before_action` approach. In the past, I have found (in my own projects) that using `before_action` can lead to difficult-to-diagnose bugs. But then again, I am adept at creating difficult-to-diagnose bugs. So, proceed as you prefer.

Oh, and finally, I used `assign_attributes` instead of `update`. `assign_attributes` doesn't do a save, which provides you with the opportunity to do `establishment.valid?` and handle the case where the provided attributes are not valid. In such a case, the `:unprocessable_entity` status is (appropriately) returned along with full error messages.

If you like, you could go a little overboard and do something like:

```
  def update
    authorized ? update : unauthorized
  end

private

  def authorized?
    return false unless current_user && current_user.email_address
    return false unless establishment && establishment.email_address
    current_user.email_address == establishment.email_address
  end

  def establishment
    @establishment ||= find_establishment 
  end

  def find_establishment
    Establishment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def unauthorized
    render json: {status: 'Not Verified'}, status: :unauthorized
  end

  def update
    establishment.assign_attributes(establishment_params)
    establishment.valid ? save_and_return : return_errors
  end

  def save_and_return
    establishment.save!
    render json: {status: 'Information Updated'}, status: :ok
  end

  def return_errors
    render json: {status: 'Not Updated', errors: establishment.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
```

Personally, I like a lot of tiny methods each of which has a very specific purpose as opposed to large methods that have a lot going on in them. This is a bit overboard in this particular use case.